# Блокировка движения гироскопа по оси Y (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю игру, в которой, наклоняя свой смартфон, с помощью гироскопа можно вращать объект по оси Z. У меня получилось добавить правильный поворот, но проблема в том, что если взять смартфон в руки и начать крутиться вокруг своей оси, угол наклона объекта продолжает меняться. Я несколько дней искал ответ, но не нашел ничего, что могло бы помочь. Можно ли получать только информацию о наклонах по оси z и не считывать движение смартфона по оси y (вокруг собственной оси) в пространстве? Буду признателен за любую помощь. Я застрял.

P.S. Похожее поведение гироскопа в играх типа Traffic Racer и Traffic Rider, только при повороте смартфона объект перемещается в стороны, а мне нужно поворачивать его.

Comment: Просто присвоить значению y возвращаемому из гироскопа 0?

Comment: Это не решает проблему. Дело в том, что гироскоп считывает своё положение в пространстве, в том числе при повороте вокруг своей оси. Гироскоп не различает изменение ориентации смартфона и перемещение его в пространстве. Именно в этом проблема.

Comment: Вы хотите измерять ориентацию  смартфона относительно собственного тела?

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы поворот по z осуществлялся только при наклоне влево и вправо в любой из плоскостей, в остальных случаях поворота быть не должно.